# React testing library to work with redux-form issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-testing-library, redux-saga

Having an issue trying to test redux-forms components. I keep getting an error  `FormSection must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()` I tried a couple of different ways to implement this but the results were somewhat the same.  Here is test code.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import { render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import ContactInformation from '../components/FormSections/ContactInformation'


// Create a reducer that includes the form reducer from redux-form
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const renderContactInformation = () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ContactInformation />
    </Provider>,
  )
}

describe("<ContactInformation />", () => {
  test('it should render fields', () => {
    renderContactInformation()
    const input = screen.getByLabelText("email")
    console.log(input)
        }
      )

})
```

any thoughts? These seems like it should work but I think I am at a lost or perhaps I just confused my self. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Here is the code for the ContactInformation.

```
class ContactInformation extends Component {

  zipCodeLocation = (zip) => {
    const { dispatch, updateField, formName } = this.props

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch({
        type: actions.ZIP_CODE_SEARCH,
        zipCode: zip,
        resolve,
        reject,
      })
    })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(updateField(formName, "contactInformation.state", response.state))
        dispatch(updateField(formName, "contactInformation.city", response.city))
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log({ error }))
  }

  render() {
    const { checkEmailExistence, emailExists, requiredEmail,isExistingInvestor } = this.props
    console.log(this.props)
    const isDisable = isExistingInvestor === 'yes' ? 'disabled':''
    const isRequired = this.props.isOnboarding
    const title = 'Contact Information'
    return (
      <>
        <h3 className="formHeadingBorder">{title}</h3>
        <FormSection style={{paddingTop: "5%"}} name="contactInformation">
          <Form.Item label="First Name" required>
            <FirstNameField name="firstName" requiredMark check={isDisable} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Middle Name">
            <MiddleInitialField check={isDisable} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Last Name" required>
            <LastNameField name="lastName" check={isDisable} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item required={requiredEmail} label="Email Address" validateStatus={emailExists ? "error" : undefined}>
            <EmailField name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required={requiredEmail} check={isDisable} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Phone Number">
            <div className={styles.multiFormItem}>
              <div className={styles.phoneNumberField}>
                <PhoneNumberField name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" check={isDisable} />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.inlineFormItem}>
                <RadioField name="isMobile" label="Mobile">
                  <Radio value="yes">Yes</Radio>
                  <Radio value="no">No</Radio>
                </RadioField>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Physical Address">
            <StreetOneField placeholder="Address Line 1" check={isDisable} isStreetRequired={isRequired} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label=" ">
            <StreetTwoField placeholder="Address Line 2" check={isDisable} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Postal Code">
            <div className={styles.multiFormItem}>
              <ZipField isZipRequired={isRequired} placeholder="Postal Code" onBlur={e => this.zipCodeLocation(e.target.value)} check={isDisable} />
              <StateField check={isDisable} />
            </div>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="City">
            <CityField isCityRequired={isRequired} placeholder="City" check={isDisable} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Country">
            <CountryField placeholder="Country" />
          </Form.Item>
        </FormSection>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, (dispatch) => {
  return{
    dispatch,
    updateField: (formName, field, data) => dispatch(change( formName, field, data ))
  }
},
  )(ContactInformation)
```

Comment: Show the code of the `ContactInformation` component

Comment: @slideshowp2 let me know if that helps.  I appreciate your time

Comment: The error message is clear. Did you wrap your component with `reduxForm` HOC? See https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/#step-2-of-4-form-component

Comment: Just a general thing: you are aware that Redux-Form has been deprecated by the author over three years ago? If this is new code and you are just learning to use those technologies, you might be following outdated tutorials.

Comment: @phry depecrated?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form are we talking about the same npm package? because its still receiving updates.   and no, its an application that is very heavily written in redux-form

Comment: @chewie yes, as visible on the start page of https://redux-form.com/ with a very big hint, as well as the github repository readme: https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form (since [May 2019](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/commit/220134950b9a383554021838f6fdbf74082f6828))